# Combine dictionary according to index

Tags: python, dictionary

Let us Assume, I have a key value pair in python, such as the following.

```
a = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'test1', 'test', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

now I want to combine these values with:

```
b = {"18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28","48", "47", "46", "45", "44", "43", "42", "41", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38"}
```

Is there any way where I can combine the values from variable `a` against the \ `b` like result shown below:

```
c = {'44': ['test1'], '43': ['test2']}
```

thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve here. `b` is a set, so there is really no way to match values in `b` with those in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `zip`, something like this:

```
>>> dict(zip(b, filter(None, a)))
{'43': 'test1', '17': 'test'}
```

Take in mind this will give different results when run, as sets are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `zip` to solve your problem:

```
a = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'test1', 'test', '', '', '', '',
     '', '', '', '', '', '']
b = ["18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "48", "47", "46",
     "45", "44", "43", "42", "41", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38"]

print dict((x, y) for x, y in zip(b, a) if y != '')
```

And you will get the output:

```
{'44': 'test1', '43': 'test'}
```

If you want to learn more about such python built-in function, you may refer to this [official document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered, which makes a direct solution problematic. However, assuming you created the set for the sake of eliminating duplicates in what was originally a list, you can use a different method of duplicate removal, combined with zipping as Francisco's answer suggests, though without the filter that mismatches the items:

```
a = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'test1', 'test', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
b_list = ["18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28","48", "47", "46", "45", "44", "43", "42", "41", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "18", "17"]  
# added hypothetical duplicates to b for the sake of showing how they're removed below
b = sorted(set(b_list), key=lambda x: b_list.index(x))

c = dict(zip(a, b))
del c['']  # removes the erroneous '' key
```

Outputs exactly what you want:

```
{'44': 'test1', '43': 'test'}
```

Comment: it doesn't need to sort. I just need to get the value of `b` where the index value of `a` occurred. In my example the index of `a` that contains value is 20 and 21, so I just need to get value 44 and 43 from `b` .

Comment: The sort in my example is assuming a different starting point with duplicates. It's only to allow an alternative to set for removing those duplicates, not actually sorting the list in order. The output to my example, if you use your a and b above is {'44': 'test1', '43': 'test'}. I updated the code above so you can run it and test.